# test class code coverage problem approval process with processs instance workitems

Tags: unit-test, batch, approval-process, code, code-coverage

in below test class is not covering the BatchSendEmailAlerts8 code guide me where i am wrong...not covering part:

```
mailIdsMap.put(PIobj.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,PIobj.actor.email);
```

and

```
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            Database.rollback(sp);
           List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email : mails) 
            {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                emailToSend.setToAddresses(email.getToAddresses());
                emailToSend.setPlainTextBody(email.getPlainTextBody());
                emailToSend.setHTMLBody(email.getHTMLBody());
                emailToSend.setSubject(email.getSubject());
                lstMsgsToSend.add(emailToSend);
             }
            if(lstMsgsToSend!=null && lstMsgsToSend.size()>0)
            {
                Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgsToSend);            
            }
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My Batch class:

```
global class BatchSendEmailAlerts8 implements Database.Batchable<sobject> 
{
  public List<Apply_Job__c> opptyUpdateList = new List<Apply_Job__c>();
 Public String query='select Id,Status__c,Next_Alert_Schduled_Date__c from Apply_Job__c where Next_Alert_Schduled_Date__c=today ';
 public set<id> applyJobIds = new set<id>();
 public map<id,string> mailIdsMap = new map<id,string>(); 

 global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC)
 {
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
 }   
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, LIST<Apply_Job__c> applyJoblist)
 {
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  system.debug('test--->'+applyJoblist);
  if(applyJoblist!=null && applyJoblist.size()>0)
    {
        for(Apply_Job__c applyObjRec: applyJoblist)
        {
          applyJobIds.add(applyObjRec.id);
        }       
    }
      if(applyJobIds !=null && applyJobIds.size()>0)
    {
        for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem PIobj: [select id,ActorId,ProcessInstanceId,actor.email,ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId from ProcessInstanceWorkitem where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId in: applyJobIds])
        {
            mailIdsMap.put(PIobj.ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId,PIobj.actor.email);
        }
    }
    system.debug('~~~~~~~~~~~~opptylist'+mailIdsMap);
    for(Apply_Job__c opptyRec: applyJoblist)
    {
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
         sendTo.add(mailIdsMap.get(opptyRec.id));
         system.debug('opptyRec.id'+mailIdsMap.get(opptyRec.id));
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
      mail.setReplyTo('kyerru@gmail.com');
      mail.setSenderDisplayName('Official Remainder Email');
      List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
      ccTo.add('kyerru@gmail.com');
      mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
      mail.setSubject('Official Remainder Email888');
      mail.setHtmlBody('Official Remainder Email'); 
      mails.add(mail);

     OpptyRec.Next_Alert_Schduled_Date__c = system.today()+1;
     opptyUpdateList.add(OpptyRec);
    }
    system.debug('^^^^^^^'+opptyUpdateList);
    try
    {
        if(opptyUpdateList !=null && opptyUpdateList.size()>0)
        {
            update opptyUpdateList;
        }
       if(mails!=null && mails.size()>0)
        {
            //Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
            Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            Database.rollback(sp);
           List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email : mails) 
            {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                emailToSend.setToAddresses(email.getToAddresses());
                emailToSend.setPlainTextBody(email.getPlainTextBody());
                emailToSend.setHTMLBody(email.getHTMLBody());
                emailToSend.setSubject(email.getSubject());
                lstMsgsToSend.add(emailToSend);
             }
            if(lstMsgsToSend!=null && lstMsgsToSend.size()>0)
            {
                Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgsToSend);            
            }               
        }
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
 }

 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
 {
    //do nothing


 }

}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class BatchSendEmailAlerts8Test{
    public static testMethod void method1(){
        List<Apply_Job__c> applyLst = new List<Apply_Job__c>();

        Apply_Job__c apply = new Apply_Job__c();
        apply.Status__c = 'Pending Approval';
        apply.Qualification__c='B.pham';
        apply.Next_Alert_Schduled_Date__c = system.today();
        insert apply;
        applyLst.add(apply);

        Apply_Job__c apply1 = new Apply_Job__c();
        apply1.Status__c = 'Pending Approval';
         apply1.Qualification__c='B.pham';
        apply1.Next_Alert_Schduled_Date__c= system.today();
        insert apply1;
        applyLst.add(apply1);

        Apply_Job__c apply2 = new Apply_Job__c();
        apply2.Status__c = 'Pending Approval';
         apply2.Qualification__c='B.pham';
        apply2.Next_Alert_Schduled_Date__c= system.today();
        insert apply2;
        applyLst.add(apply2);

     try {   

    for(Apply_Job__c a: applyLst) {

     // Create an approval for the account and submit
     Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest AccountRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest(); 
     AccountRequest.setObjectId(a.ID);  
     Approval.ProcessResult AccountRequestResult = Approval.Process(AccountRequest);
     ProcessInstanceWorkitem pworkItem = new ProcessInstanceWorkitem();
    pworkItem.ActorId = userinfo.getuserId();
    pworkItem.OriginalActorId = userinfo.getuserId();
    pworkItem.ProcessInstanceId = AccountRequestResult.ID;
     insert pworkItem;
     System.assert(AccountRequestResult.isSuccess());   

    } // loop thru accounts submitting them for approval

   } catch (DMLException e) {
    system.debug('>>>> NO APPROVAL PROCESS FOR ACCOUNTS!');
   }


        BatchSendEmailAlerts8 batch = new BatchSendEmailAlerts8();
        Test.StartTest();
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.StopTest();



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only in rare cases that one would ever need to use a try-catch block in a test class. It's unclear to me why you've used one in your test class above.

I don't see where you're creating all the data in your test class to be able to process the related records required for your batch class. I don't see the opportunity records that it uses, nor the accounts and contact records referenced in the messaging.sendEmail(emailList) that you've commented in your class.

Of greater importance is that you should be asserting after the `Test.StopTest()` that your batch class has run. Get the `jobId` before you call the start method, then query that it's run afterward. You can also query that the DML has been performed on the email method to show that you called it. You can use the limits method to get that coverage.

Comment: Additionally, DML inside for loops, 3 inserts adding to list after each, instead of adding to list and doing 1 dml. Lots of what not to do in the code

Comment: @Eric. He only asked why he didn't have the coverage. Not how to improve his batch class. The latter is an entirely different question. ;)

Comment: Hehe - Then you should remove : "Of greater importance is that you should be asserting after the Test.StopTest() that your batch class has run......" from your answer? - All in jest :)

Comment: plz suggest how to write a test class for above batchapex...

Comment: crmprogdev.  Eric.  please suggest for write a test class for above batch class...correct me ...thanks

Comment: @YK88YK. You need to start by creating Accounts and related Contacts, followed by Opportunities that are apparently related to your `Apply_Job__c` records. I can't tell what your process does to know if you're creating accounts for them & asking for approval. At a minimum, you'd need leads or contacts to start with. You know your schema better than we do. Regardless, it's clear that you don't have all the data needed to process the records.